# How to trigger images to load in background using Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image

We have a GIF that is 11mb in the homepage, a bit large, but it is a business requirement.
I wish to start downloading the GIF in background, while the "Loading" page is playing out, so that when the home is shown after 2 seconds, the GIF is already downloaded (or almost).

How should I approach this in Next.js? Is that a hack parameter that can solve this using the `Image` component?

I think the problem is that, since `Image` for the GIF is only declared in the Home page, it won't start loading until the component is rendered by Next. How can I overcome this?

**Image GIF declaration inside the Home**

```js
<Image
  src={"/assets/home.gif"}
  alt=""
  layout="fill"
  loading="eager"
  priority
  placeholder="blur"
  blurDataURL="/assets/home_blur.png"
/>
```

**Main page that showd the Loading page before the Home**

```js
function MainPage(show) {
  return show ? (
    return (
    <Home />
  )) : (
    <Loading />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a best practice solution but I was able to trigger it using `visibility: hidden;`

```js
const divClass = state.firstTime ? styles.hidden : styles.visible;

// Declare the image in the loading screen
return (
    <div className={divClass}>
        <SlidesDiv>
            <Image
                src="/assets/home.gif"
                height={1000}
                width={1000}
                alt=""
                priority="true"
            />
        </SlidesDiv>
    </div>
)

// In my styles file
.hidden {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.visible {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
}
```